# How to connect PostgreSQL 64 bit using Apache (on XAMPP) 32 bit

Tags: apache, xampp, postgresql-9.2

First, I was installed the xampp 32 bit and postgresql 64 bit (because my OS is 64 bit) on my laptop

I've heard from my lecturer that the apache 32 bit can't connect with postgresql 64 bit (in other words I must install the 32 bit version of postgresql) is that true?

If there are several step that I must do to connect my postgre, let me know...

Comment: You may have a 32 bits client talking to a 64 bits postgresql server, it works.

Comment: I have the same problem, have you found the solution ?